How to install VimTex on Neovim (NvChad) on Windows (not WSL)
Hi I’m trying to install VimTex in NvChad on Windows (not WSL), but I’m not sure what to do, the official Git page wasn’t of much help, and I’ve been stuck for hours.
I want to know what I must download, or write in the init.lua to configure the plugin.

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

You need to modify the file: ~/nvim/lua/custom/plugins.lua by adding the following section:
{
  "lervag/vimtex",
  lazy = false,     -- we don't want to lazy load VimTeX
  -- tag = "v2.15", -- uncomment to pin to a specific release
  init = function()
    -- VimTeX configuration goes here, e.g.
    vim.g.vimtex_view_method = "zathura"
  end
}

to the local plugins table.
Namely
local plugins = {
  -- other plugins defined here
  -- each {} section separated by a comma ','
  -- ...
  {
    "lervag/vimtex",
    lazy = false,     -- we don't want to lazy load VimTeX
    -- tag = "v2.15", -- uncomment to pin to a specific release
    init = function()
      -- VimTeX configuration goes here, e.g.
      vim.g.vimtex_view_method = "zathura"
    end
  }
}

return plugins

